# Knex.JS - How does one compare a lowercased input against lowercased field values?

Tags: javascript, database, sql-like, knex.js

So, I'm using Knex.JS for my database. And I want to compare lowercased inputs against lowercased field values. I thought I could `knex.raw` it, but apparently my script breaks when I try it. Has anyone ever successfully done a `LIKE` comparison with lowercased values in Knex.JS? And if you did, how'd you do it?

Any help is as always, greatly appreciated.

```js
function findUsers(q) {
  return db("users")
    .where(
      knex.raw(`'LOWER("firstname")', "like", %${q.toLowerCase()}%`, "knex")
    )
    .orWhere("lastname", "like", `%${q}%`)
    .orWhere("username", "like", `%${q}%`)
    .orWhere("email", "like", `%${q}%`);
}
```

Comment: `apparently my script breaks` in what way?

Comment: @JaromandaX - It doesn't return any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the values in `lower()` like:

```js
function findUsers(q) {
  return db('users')
    .where(knex.raw('lower("firstname")'), 'like', `%${q.toLowerCase()}%`)
    .orWhere(knex.raw('lower("lastname")'), 'like', `%${q}%`)
    .orWhere(knex.raw('lower("username")'), 'like', `%${q}%`)
    .orWhere(knex.raw('lower("email")'), 'like', `%${q}%`);
}
```

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/233#issuecomment-656452967).

Comment: This answer didn't exactly work, but the advice on the GitHub issue did, so I'm marking it as the answer.

The thing that worked was using `whereRaw`.

Thanks!